# Stop MySQL after first match

Tags: mysql

I noticed that adding `LIMIT 1` at the end of a query does not decrease the execution time. I have a few thousand records and a simple query. How do I make MySQL stop after the first match?

For example, these two queries both take approximately half a second:

```
SELECT id,content FROM links WHERE LENGTH(content)<500 ORDER BY likes

SELECT id,content FROM links WHERE LENGTH(content)<500 ORDER BY likes LIMIT 1
```

**Edit:** And here's the explain results:

```
id | select_type | table | type possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1 | SIMPLE | links | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 38556 | Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY doesn't make a lot of sense - unless you're really only interested in whether or not a concept EXISTS within a table.

Comment: Get the execution plan with `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE LENGTH(col)<500 LIMIT 1;` Half a second it's too much for getting a single record.

Comment: How many records in the table are under 500 characters? How many are above? The time it takes to find the 'first' record may be similar to the time it takes to find all of them (the extreme case would be only one record which answers the condition which is the last one to be scanned)... Note that no index can be used to find records which satisfy the length condition.

Comment: @Galz About 66% of the records have a length of less than 500 characters.

Comment: Of course it makes no (noticeable) difference in your example, because the _combination_ of ORDER BY and LIMIT requires to select all records matching the WHERE criterion first anyway, so that they can be brought into the specified ORDER – LIMIT is only applied after that (naturally).

Comment: Do you have an index on the "likes" column?

Comment: @CBroe I tried this query as well, with the same running time: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,content FROM links ORDER BY likes DESC) t WHERE LENGTH(content)<500 LIMIT 1`

@WillPalmer No index.

Comment: @Linksku - Please read my edit. If you have no index on likes, there is a full table scan anyway (with or without LIMIT), and a sort of all records as well. Only then the LIMIT kicks in and saves very little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two queries run time relies on the actual data.

There are several possible scenarios:

**There are many records with `LENGTH(content)<500`**

In this case, MySQL will start scanning all table rows (according to primary key order since you didn't provide any ORDER BY).
There is no index use since your WHERE condition can't be indexed.
Since there are relatively many rows with `LENGTH(content)<500`, the LIMIT query will return faster than the other one.

**There are no records with `LENGTH(content)<500`**
Again, MySQL will start scanning all table rows, but will have to go through all records to figure out none of them satisfies the condition.
Again no index can be used for the same reason.
In this case - the two queries will have exactly the same run time.

Anything between those two scenarios will have different run times, which will be farther apart as you have more valid records in the table.

**Edit**
Now that you added the ORDER BY, the answer is a bit different:

- If there is an index on likes column, ORDER BY would use it and the time would be the time  it takes to get to the first record that satisfies the WHERE condition (if 66% of the records do, than this should be faster than without the LIMIT).
- If there is no index on likes column, the ORDER BY will take most of the time - MySQL must scan all table to get all records that satisfy the WHERE, then order them by likes, and then take the first one.
  In this case both queries will have similar run time (scanning and sorting the results is much longer than returning 1 record or many records...)!

Comment: Adding an index fixed it for now. However, I already have several (more important) indexes on the table and I don't want to add any more. Why wouldn't this query work: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,content FROM links ORDER BY likes DESC) t WHERE LENGTH(content)<500 LIMIT 1`. My understanding is that it would create an ordered table first, and only check the WHERE clause up to the first matched record.

Comment: @Linksku Creating the ordered table requires a full table scan - this is what takes most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Calling functions on data results in an automatic table scan, these can't be indexed. What you might do is create a derived column where you've saved this value in advance if performance is a concern here:

```
ALTER TABLE links ADD COLUMN content_length INT
UPDATE links SET content_length=LENGTH(content)
ALTER TABLE links ADD INDEX idx_content_length (content_length)
```

Once denormalized like this and properly you'll be able to run the query much faster. Keep in mind you'll have to populate `content_length` each time you add a record.